# How do I get a unique integer for each unique item using ROW_NUMBER() and RANK() within the same query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, window-functions

I know how I would do this using a temp table, but I want to know how to do this using both `ROW_NUMBER()` and `RANK()` for my own learning.

Data:

```
Item    Desc       Qty  Row
ItemA   ItemDescA  10   1
ItemA   ItemDescA  20   2
ItemB   ItemDescB  30   3
ItemB   ItemDescB  40   4
ItemB   ItemDescB  50   5
ItemC   ItemDescC  60   6
```

Desired Result:

```
Item    Desc       Qty  Row  ItemRow
ItemA   ItemDescA  10   1    1
ItemA   ItemDescA  20   2    1
ItemB   ItemDescB  30   3    2
ItemB   ItemDescB  40   4    2
ItemB   ItemDescB  50   5    2
ItemC   ItemDescC  60   6    3
```

My code:

```
select

    so.*
    , row_number() over(order by so.[Item], so.Qty) row --this gives me the Row column shown above
    --I want to add a single line here using ROW_NUMBER() or RANK() to accomplish this

from

    #StockOrdersData so
```

Comment: The second data set looks like you want `DENSE_RANK` ordered on the value of `desc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The window function *Dense_Rank* will give you a unique value per value of `Item`

For example:

```
with t as (
  select * from(values('ItemA'), ('ItemA'), ('ItemB'), ('ItemB'), ('ItemB'), ('ItemC'))t(Item)
)
select *, Dense_Rank() over(order by item) Itemrow
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

`dense_rank()` will create a rank based on the `Order by` clause and `partition by` clause. In your case you are not interested in specific granularity so we don't need the partition by clause.

the rank will be created based on the item name in `ASC` order. If the names are similar the same rank will be provided. In the case of `row_number`, if the same names are there, this would have created rank 1,2 for item A and rank 1,2,3 for item B, and 1 for item C. This is because `row_number()` doesn't look at ties.

`Rank()` on the other hand would have produced 1,1 for item A and 3,3,3 for item B as it skips the ranks when there is a repetition of values

Your desired results can be achieved by `dense rank`

```
select 
*,
dense_rank() over(order by item) as rank
from table
```